# Firebase Realtime Database backend

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm very new to Firebase. I'm building an e-commerce app using Firebase as the backend and Android Studio as the front end. In a DB, I have this tree:

Man
clothing
shorts
Product 1
Image   ..
Name    ..
Price   ..
Size    ..

Is it possible to have a size with multiple choices (for example Size 1, Size 2, Size 3, etc.)? How do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in Firebase Realtime Database is stored as JSON and it is possible to use nested JSON as for your database structure. See sample database structure below:

```
{
  "products": {
    "productId": {
      "image": "path/to/image.png",
      "name": "Product Name",
      "price": 1,
      "sizes": {
        "pushId1": 1,
        "pushId2": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your question, those fields are of type string. Such a field can only store a single value. If you want to store multiple values in a field, then you have to choose to use an array. So you can add all those sizes in an array. So your schema might look like this:

```
db
|
--- products
     |
     --- productId
          |
          --- name: "T-shirt"
          |
          --- price: 19.99
          |
          --- image: "https://..."
          |
          --- size
               |
               --- 0: "S"
               |
               --- 1: "M"
               |
               --- 2: "L"
               |
               --- 3: "S"
               |
               --- 4: "XL"
               |
               --- 5: "XXL"
```

In this example, the `size` field is of type array and holds `S` at index `0`, `M` at index 1, and so on.

Comment: Hey Eva. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Hi Alex, yes I did. Thanks for your help!